# Changing custom thumb's parameters inside a custom slider's trigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is my custom thumb, for a slider:

```
 <Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle" TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="18"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="18"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="thumbBorder" 
                        CornerRadius="9,0,0,9"
                            Background="DimGray"/>

                    <Ellipse x:Name="thumbEllipse"  
                              Fill="Orange"></Ellipse>
                </Grid>


            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>      
</Style>
```

And this is how I'm using it inside a slider custom control:

```
 <Style TargetType="Slider">
<Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
 <Setter Property="Value" Value="5"></Setter>
   <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
            <Grid>   
                    <Border Name="PART_Border" 
                        CornerRadius="9" 
                        Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                        Height="18"
                        Background="Red"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                    <Track Name="PART_Track" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"   
                           Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                           Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Command="Slider.DecreaseLarge" 
                                      Style="{StaticResource SliderButtonStyle}" />
                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <Track.Thumb>
                        <Thumb x:Name="myThumb"
                            Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}" />
                    </Track.Thumb>
                        <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                            <RepeatButton Command="Slider.IncreaseLarge" 
                                       Style="{StaticResource DecreaseSliderButtonStyle}"/>
                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                </Track>                   
            </Grid>   

            <!-- this is the part I would like to change, so I can modify myThumb's border / ellipse: -->
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger SourceName="PART_Track" Property="Value" Value="10">
                        <Setter TargetName="myThumb" Property="Width" Value="50"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

In a commented part, I've managed to modify the thumb via triggers, when the maximum value is reached: is there any way I can modify custom thumb's parts this way, like its Border (x:thumbBorder) or Ellipse (x:thumbEllipse)?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is set the Tag property on your Thumb in Slider's ControlTemplate.Triggers and then in Thumb's ControlTemplate you can put trigger over Tag property to change you want to do on its ControlTemplate contents like border or ellipse.

i.e in Slider's ControlTemplate.Triggers

```
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger SourceName="PART_Track" Property="Value" Value="10">
                    <Setter TargetName="myThumb" Property="Tag" Value="50"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

and inside Thumb controlTemplate

```
         <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Value="50">
                    <Setter TargetName="thumbEllipse" Property="Fill" Value="Red"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: It looks promising, however it doesn't work. [There's code, if you are willing to take a look.](http://pastebin.com/RygnBGj1)