# Access Control Template's children inside code in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This thumb is used inside a custom control slider. Is there any way I can access thumbBorder inside the code?

```
<Style x:Key="SliderThumbStyle" TargetType="Thumb">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="thumbBorder"
                            CornerRadius="9,0,0,9"
                            Background="DimGray" />

                    <Ellipse x:Name="thumbEllipse"
                             Fill="Orange">
                    </Ellipse>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>       
</Style>
```

Comment: What do you want that for?

Comment: @HighCore I want to be able to modify it from a Slider's custom control (its parent) - I desribed my problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19080627/2759011), but it didn't help me much, so I'm looking for another solution.

Comment: If you're creating a `Custom Control`, you should look into `OnApplyTemplate()` to get the reference to the template part. Inspecting the Visual Tree with `VisualTreeHelper` is not an optimal approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the VisualTreeHelper to navigate through the visual tree of you thumb and find any child (border/ellipse) in it.
Below is the simplest way to find the child of particular type

```
private static DependencyObject RecursiveVisualChildFinder<T>(DependencyObject rootObject)  
{  
    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(rootObject, 0);  
    if (child == null) return null;  

    return child.GetType() == typeof (T) ? child : RecursiveVisualChildFinder<T>(child);  
}
```

you can update this function to check the child Name also to return